# Howto handle a maven2 junit test project with artefact dependencies?

Tags: maven-2, junit

I have a project 'ABC' with the main code and junit tests. I do have the requirement that i can execute the set unit tests against a older version of the product artefacts.

To solve this requirement i would create a maven project which only contains the junit tests. 
Another maven product builds my product code and places the artifact into the repository. 
Now i could launch my tests against any product build by changing the build dependency within the junit test project.

Is this a good solution? Are there perhaps better solutions to solve this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

I think thats a pretty good approach. You could create a profile for each old version and then  activate them via the profile name and test different old versions without having to change the pom file for each run. You could then also run the different profiles separately scheduled on a continuous integration server...